# Unable to start activity of embedded Wear App, on Wear device

Tags: android, android-activity, classnotfoundexception, wear-os

When I push the APK onto the phone with an embedded Wear App, and then go to Start..., then try to run my application, it crashes on the watch.  The Exception is a ClassNotFoundException.

```
09-18 14:53:17.678: E/AndroidRuntime(2391): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.WearActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.WearActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.myapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I have declared this Activity in my wearable AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >

   <activity
        android:name=".WearActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have also double checked that the package name aligns with whats declared above, and it does.

In the build.gradle file for the wearable module, I have proguard turned off

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Really not sure what else would be preventing the OS from finding the Activity. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `com.myapp` a valid package for `WearActivity` class? Please check where your `WearActivity` is located.

Comment: In my question I have mentioned I have already done this :)

Comment: You didn't posted your Activity class, so just needed to be sure :) You said that you push the app to phone so it "should" be also installed on Android Wear. Are you sure that the newest version of wearable app is actually installed on watch? Maybe there is some old version  that doesn't have this `WearActivity`? Try to uninstall it from watch and see if it would be properly installed again. BTW: does it worked when you pushed the wearable apk (signed with debug key) to watch directly (without relying on installing signed apk from phone)? Please tell me that - it will eliminate some cases:)

Comment: As of right now its not being installed on the watch from the phone. Troubleshooting !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the following build.gradle entries were conflicting.

**Mobile**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
```

**Wear**

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
```

---

By explicitly declaring the version numbers, the issue went away.

**Mobile**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
```

**Wear**

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:5.0.77'
```

Comment: did you somehow notice that your watch actually had older apk? may be thats why it didn't had some expected class? For me I m facing strange issue... When ever i try to uninstall app from phone (it also uninstall the wear version) then I install a new signed apk. But the auto installation in watch, it actually install the last (old) version! 
I also try clearing the data of android wear app on phone. The issue is only solved when i uninstall the app explicitly on both devices and uninstall the android wear app itself (the app which is responsible for connecting watch). Then do a fresh install!

Comment: i never noticed that, but i did notice that sometimes theres a delay while the app transfers the apk to the wearable over bluetooth. usually it will exit out of the old app upon a successful installation though. i've also noticed that there are bugs in gradle which i remedy by `gradle --stop` and then a project clean